# What does value="/{1}" mean in tile xml? (Apache Tiles, JSP)

Tags: xml, jsp, tiles

I am looking at some code in tile-common.xml.   In "put-attribute" element, value attributes have something like {1} {2} {3}.

**1) Can anyone guess what this stands for?**

**2) Possibly jsp mapping? If so, what kinds of files should I look for to figure out what {1} {2} {3} means?**

```
<definition name="/*.tiles" extends="layout">

    <put-attribute name="includeFile"  value="/{1}" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}.jsp"/>  
</definition>

<definition name="/*/*.tiles" extends="layout">

    <put-attribute name="includeFile"  value="/{1}/{2}" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/*/*/*.tiles" extends="layout">       

    <put-attribute name="includeFile"  value="/{1}/{2}/{3}" />
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}/{2}/{3}.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to figure this out. Hope this helps someone.

**{1} and ***(asterisk, star, or wildcard)  were used in Apache Tiles.

> 1. {1} means the first *
> 2. {2} means the second *
> 3. {3} means the third *

For example, /a.tiles will be used as value="/a" in 'includeFile' and value="/a.jsp" in 'content'

You will find more detailed explanation in the link below. (Note that Tiles retired. In the Attic now)

[Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html)